# I am not able to pull from docker registry when running command behind the proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

I am getting above error response, but i am able to connect with internet from my system using the same proxy. ( I have username and passowrd in my proxy link)

export http_proxy=http://:@proxyurl:8080

Answer (score 2):

1.Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

2.Create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
```

Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf` that adds the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
```

3.Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

4.Restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Docker has published the above info with some additional info at https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:
create a file in the below location:
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
and set proxy in it

```
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<host>:8080"
```