# Configure Docker to use a proxy server

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have installed docker on windows , when I try to run `hello-world` for testing on docker. I get following error

> Unable to find image

My computer is using proxy server for communication. I need to configure that server in the docker. I know proxy server address and port. Where I need to update this setting. I tried using https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#set-the-environment-variables-manually.
It is  not working.

Comment: are you using docker for windows, docker for mac or docker toolbox or on linux

Comment: docker for windows

Comment: docker run --env HTTP_PROXY="http://192.168.2.24:89"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: the answer stopped working or what? you had accepted it right?

Comment: oh really . it was a mistake .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the proxy. Right click on the docker icon in system tray, go to settings, proxy and add the below settings:

```
"HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
```

If you are looking to set a proxy on Linux, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355276/i-am-not-able-to-pull-from-docker-registry-when-running-command-behind-the-proxy/55372084#55372084)

Comment: username = my username,password = my password, host = my local ip which shows in ipconfig command, port=? Can you example PLEASE? I AM STUCKED FOR 2 HRS

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Alexandre Mélard at question [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy#answer-28093517) works, here is the simplified version:

1. Find out the systemd script or init.d script path of the docker service by running:`service docker status` or `systemctl status docker`, for example in Ubuntu16.04 it's at `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
2. Edit the script for example `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/docker.service` by adding the following in the `[Service]` section:

   ```
    Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy_host>:<port>"
    Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy_host>:<port>"
    Environment="NO_PROXY=<no_proxy_host_or_ip>,<e.g.:172.10.10.10>"
   ```
3. Reload and restart the daemon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart docker` or `sudo service docker restart`
4. Verify: `docker info | grep -i proxy` should show something like:

   ```
   HTTP Proxy: http://10.10.10.10:3128
   HTTPS Proxy: http://10.10.10.10:3128
   ```
5. This adds the proxy for `docker pull`, which is the problem of the question. If for running or building docker a proxy is needed, either configure `~/.docker/config` as the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) explained, or change Dockerfile so there is proxy inside the container.

Comment: I don't see any answer authored by Peter to the question you link. Please correct that, and set the link target to the answer itself, not to its author.

Comment: I doubt the system.d-based approach applies to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a windows server and solved the problem by setting the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` on powershell:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

And then restarting docker:

```
Restart-Service docker
```

More information at [Microsoft official proxy-configuration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#proxy-configuration).

Note: The error returned when pulling image, with version 19.03.5, was `connection refused`.